# Storyboard instantiation not returning exception on fail

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create and return a **Storyboard** programmatically while *preventing a crash* checking for an exception per Apple's documentation on UIStoryboard.

This method should return an exception if the storyboard mentioned doesn't exist:

```
init(name name: String,
   bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)
```

As it stands putting the following code:

```
do {
    let storyboard = try UIStoryboard(name: "tester", bundle: nil)
} catch {
    // Do something
}
```

in a do-catch clause is being met by the pre-compiler with the following warning that the method:

> 'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do'
>   block

**Might this be a bug?**

Edit: 2015/11/19
After sending a radar to Apple about it, they have responded with the fact the issue is known and that my report is a duplicate of an open one.

Answer (score -1):

The UIStoryboard initializer is not marked with **throws** hence you don't need to put it in a do-try-catch block

```
init(name name: String,
   bundle storyboardBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)
```

is enough then to change your code to

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "tester", bundle: nil)
```

Notice that do-try-catch only catches errors and not NSException

You could read more about it [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7582)

If you want still to try to catch the NSException in that case you could see this answer: [Catching NSException in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift)

Comment: It's do catch, not try catch, and you don't need the try if it doesn't throw (in the second code example)

Comment: Directly from the documentation:
Return Value:
A storyboard object for the specified file. If no storyboard resource file matching name exists, an exception is thrown with description: Could not find a storyboard named 'XXXXXX' in bundle....

It's supposed to throw.. So my question is, is this a bug or a problem in documentation... An app WILL crash if the name is faulty btw.

Comment: @Tokuriku https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

And you are using do-try-catch for ERROR handling, no exception handling in Swift

Comment: Please try and answer the question

Comment: @Tokuriku yes I know perfectly that the app crashes.
Anyway from iOS Developer Library:


NOTE

Error handling in Swift resembles exception handling in other languages, with the use of the try, catch and throw keywords.

Comment: You won't catch NSExceptions in Swift

Comment: If you want then to catch NSException you could try something like here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift