# xcode catch exception NSRangeException

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, error-handling, exception

I have an error with handling exceptions, and every time I open my app **after** the first launch, the app is terminated. My app is one where, once launched, data is inputted using a UI table view.

Is there a way to catch the error so that the app doesn't terminate? Please help.

Master View Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      firstLaunchOfApp()
}


//MARK: - Check for first launch
func firstLaunchOfApp() {
    let launchedBefore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore  {
        print("Not first launch.")
        let index = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
        tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .Top)
        pushNewValuesToDetail()
    }
    else {
        print("First launch, setting NSUserDefault.")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.addNewCourseWork()
        }

    }
}
```

XCode Message:

Not first launch.
2016-05-11 16:27:45.530 CWCoreData[96559:855380] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

Comment: probably tableview is not loaded yet, call tableview.reloadData before that,or select in viewWillAppear

Comment: tried placing "firstLaunchOfApp()"  in ViewWillAppear - same error. How would I go about calling tableview.reloadData?

Comment: The table.reloadData won't work as view has not loaded yet.Try the code in viewdidAppear

Comment: view has loaded and thats why viewDidLoad is called :) even the name says it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catching NSException in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is crashing because when viewdidload fires the table is not yet populated so their is no row to select.Try doing that in viewdidAppear method.

Comment: I said viewdidAppear not ViewWillAppear :)

Comment: Don't have ViewDidAppear in my file. Do I just create it?

Comment: Yes it is a function just like viewdidload.

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) { }.This is the function

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch the exception, Swift's `do` and `catch` statements won't help as it's an Objective-C exception.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454808/1072846) provides a good solution.