# Swift 3: How to catch error if NSCoder decodeX function decodes wrong value type?

Tags: swift, swift3

Swift 3 changes how NSCoder works.

As other SO questions mention, to decode value types like `Int` or `Bool`, you must use a specific function. For instance, [decodeInteger](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscoder/1409246-decodeinteger) is used to decode `Int` values like so:

```
let value = decodeInteger(forKey key: TestKey)
```

But what if the value returned from `decodeInteger` is a `String` or `Bool` or something other than an `Int`?

Or what if TestKey actually maps to nothing because it contains the wrong key data?

How do you catch these errors gracefully?

Comment: @LeoDabus 0 is a valid integer. How do you distinguish between a valid and invalid case of 0?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `decodeInteger` on a non-integer key would raise an exception. Sadly, it's an `NSException` which Swift cannot handle directly (see references below).

You need to first write a wrapper to handle ObjC exceptions in ObjC and bridge it over to Swift (inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454808/2538939)):

```
/// -------------------------------------------
/// ObjC.h
/// -------------------------------------------
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ObjC : NSObject

+ (BOOL)catchException:(void(^)())tryBlock error:(__autoreleasing NSError **)error;

@end

/// -------------------------------------------
/// ObjC.m
/// -------------------------------------------
#import "ObjC.h"

@implementation ObjC

+ (BOOL)catchException:(void(^)())tryBlock error:(__autoreleasing NSError **)error {
    @try {
        tryBlock();
        return YES;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSMutableDictionary * userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:exception.userInfo];
        [userInfo setValue:exception.reason forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        [userInfo setValue:exception.name forKey:NSUnderlyingErrorKey];

        *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:exception.name
                                            code:0
                                        userInfo:userInfo];
        return NO;
    }
}

@end
```

Now you can catch the exception in Swift:

```
do {
    try ObjC.catchException {
        let age = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "firstName")
    }
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

---

**References**: [Using ObjectiveC with Swift: Adopting Cocoa Design Patterns](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID10)

> Although Swift error handling resembles exception handling in Objective-C, it is entirely separate functionality. If an Objective-C method throws an exception during runtime, Swift triggers a runtime error. There is no way to recover from Objective-C exceptions directly in Swift. Any exception handling behavior must be implemented in Objective-C code used by Swift.

Comment: So is it incorrect to say this is much worse than Swift 2 which let you catch errors like this: `if let value = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(TestKey) as? Bool {
   test = value
}`

Comment: I don't have Xcode 7 to test that, but if it did work on Swift 2, then yes, Swift 3 made it worse. And this won't be the only thing made worse by Swift 3. Pointer was a pain in Swift 2, a much bigger pain in Swift 3

Comment: Not related to your question. If you deal with C libraries that work with pointers, interfacing with them in Swift is a pain in the ass