# How to handle NSInvalidArgumentException thrown when fetching aggregate data from empty persistent store

Tags: core-data, swift3

I am trying to fetch data grouped by a given column.  It works well when I have data.  I want to handle the case when I have no data, because it raises an NS error that I could not catch in swift do catch block.  I've seen the answers on creating an ObjC wrapper but I it does not apply to my case because I need to return an Array of String.

```
let request = self.fetchRequest()
request.propertiesToGroupBy = [attribute]
request.propertiesToFetch = [attribute]
request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType
request.returnsDistinctResults = true

if let results = try? context().fetch(request), // raises exception in testing, but runs fine when run on simulator.
  let dics = results as? [NSDictionary] {
  var resultsArray: [Any] = []
  for dic in dics {
    if let propValue = dic[attribute] {
      resultsArray.append(propValue)
    }
  }
  return resultsArray
}
```

How might I do this?

Comment: Until I find a real solution, to move forward, I will fetch twice.  First to check if there are any data, run the actual fetch.  If no data, initialize to an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

It's recommended to wrap Core Data fetch lines **always** in a `do - catch` block because on success it returns reliably a non-optional array of the specified return type.

Swift has got a strong type system. Casting to unspecified `Any` or Foundation type `NSDictionary` doesn't help the compiler and could cause unnecessary compiler errors.

Assuming both key and value of the dictionary are `String` cast the dictionary to Swift type `[String:String]`. To forced unwrap the dictionary is absolutely safe because the Core Data model cannot be changed at runtime.

`flatMap` returns a non-optional array of all values which are not `nil`.

```
var resultsArray = [String]()
do {
   let results = try context().fetch(request) as! [[String:String]]
   resultsArray = results.flatMap {$0[attribute] as? String}       
} catch {
   print(error)
}
return resultsArray
```

Comment: I did the do-try-catch but the problem is the exception being thrown, swift cannot catch it because it is ObjC type exception.  The `fetch()` call throws it.  It works on simulator, but I worry it will break easily in the future, that is why I want it to pass my integration test.  I did find a solution though I will post it as an answer, sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift)

It was not immediately obvious to me that it can be done like this:

```
let request = self.fetchRequest()

request.propertiesToGroupBy = [attribute]
request.propertiesToFetch = [attribute]
request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType
request.returnsDistinctResults = true


var result: [Any] = []
do {
  try ObjC.catchException {
    let results = try? context().fetch(request)
    if let dics = results as? [NSDictionary] {
      var resultsArray: [Any] = []
      for dic in dics {
        if let propValue = dic[attribute] {
          resultsArray.append(propValue)
        }
      }
      result = resultsArray
    }
  }
} catch {}
return result
```

Ideally I wanted the array to be returned by `ObjC.catchException` unfortunately I have no solid grasp of ObjC yet.  The scope of the `result` var looks too wide, I welcome any suggestion to improve it.

I wanted to keep everything in swift for uniformity but I guess I am stuck with this solution for now.