# How to catch exception when use NSExpression (swift 3)

Tags: exception, swift3, try-catch, nsexpression

```
    import UIKit


func calculatorFromString(colculation:String)->Double{
    let mathExpression = try NSExpression(format: colculation)
    let mathValue = mathExpression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? Double
        return mathValue!
}

calculatorFromString(colculation: "5*(1+4)")
```

when I set colculation equal "5*(1+4)))", this is a error and I dont know how to catch exception. Thank you!

Comment: Your problem is the unbalanced parentheses "5 * (1+4)" would work. I am voting to close it as a typo

Comment: ex: var colculation = "5*(1+4)" 
func calculatorFromString will return a result 25
, if input equal "5*(1+4)))", how to catch exception.

Comment: Note that try it is not needed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching NSException in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift)

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html

**pseudo Code**

```
do {
    try expression
    statements
} catch pattern 1 {
    statements
} catch pattern 2 where condition {
    statements
}
```

hope it's help you

```
do{

try(calculatorFromString(colculation: "5*(1+4)"))

}catch {
calculatorFromString(colculation: "\(5 * (1 + 4))")
}
```

Comment: The pattern you are describing is for "error handling". The problem OP is trying to solve is "exception handling", which cannot be done in pure Swift at this point per the _Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C_ book. The only way to handle this is to use Objective-C.