# try? propagates rather than returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, option-type

My understanding of `try?` was that when the expression following `try?` is evaluated, `nil` will be returned if there is an exception, otherwise the return value of the function will be returned.

When I run the following code:

```
guard let istream = InputStream(url: url),
      let ambiguousObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: istream, options: []),
      let jsonObj = ambiguousObj as? [[String: Any]] else {
    throw ExportError.recoveredParseFailed
}
```

I get an error pertaining to the second line above:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:options:error:]: stream is not open for reading'
```

**I understand how to fix the error.** (I needed to call `istream.open()`)

But, could someone help me understand why `try?` didn't catch the exception in this case?

Comment: have you added above code in `do {  }catch{}` block?

Comment: @BalajiGalave OP is using `try?`, not `try`, no need for a Do-Catch block.

Comment: Yeah  I got it. We do not need it while try is optional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`try?` evaluates the expression and returns `nil` if a Swift *error* is thrown
during the evaluation. In your situation, the Foundation library throws
an Objective-C `NSException`, as can be seen if you set an exception breakpoint:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x00007fffbe5cb45d libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x00007fffa9855c3d CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    frame #2: 0x00007fffab3a001a Foundation`+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithStream:options:error:] + 178
```

Objective-C exceptions *cannot* be catched in Swift (unless you
use an Objective-C wrapper, see for example [Catching NSException in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift)).