# Try-catch like feature for uncertain code block in Swift 4

Tags: swift, xctest, xcuitest, xctestcase

I am writing a test in XCUITest. There is an introductory banner which may or may not come on the mobile screen while my test is in progress. I want to write my case in such a way that, if the banner is present, I have to verify certain elements on that banner and click on the "Continue" button on it, and if it is not present, I have to proceed with my test case.

I know in Java, we write such code inside a try-catch block, so that even if the banner is not found and the code fails, the pointer goes into the catch block and the remaining program continues.

When I searched on the internet, i only found such feature for single statements and not for some chunk of code block.Do we have something similar in Swift, where I can write some code inside try-catch like code block?
Please have a look at my test case and the code to click in the banner.

```
class MyTestClass: BaseTest {
    func testMapSearch() {
        do {
            let app = try XCUIApplication()
            let element = try app.children(matching: .window).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .other).element.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 1).children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 0)
            element.buttons["Continue"].tap()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }

        let logInButton = app.scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Log In"]

        checkLoginPage(login: logInButton)
        logInButton.tap()
    }
}
```

The `do` block is written to click on the "Continue" button on a banner which is not sure to be displayed on the screen. The `do` block is followed by more code. If the banner is not displayed, the code written in the `do` block fails and the test case throws an error. I want to write a case such that the login button code should get executed irrespective of the banner is displayed or not.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift/36454808#36454808

Comment: Please read the [Error Handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html) chapter in the Swift book.

Comment: The above code fails where? With what exception? Note that in Swift there is a huge difference between error and exception. It's much different than in Java.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Which line fails? What is the actual exact error? Is the `print` in your `catch` being called or not?

Comment: @rmaddy, the test fails at: element.buttons["Continue"].tap() line. And the print statement in the catch block is not executed. The error is:  t =     6.66s     Find the "Continue" Button
    t =     7.70s         Find the "Continue" Button (retry 1)
    t =     8.73s         Find the "Continue" Button (retry 2)
    t =     8.80s         Assertion Failure: MyTestClass.swift:18: No matches found for Find: Elements matching predicate '"Continue" IN identifiers' from input {(

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the two lines of code marked `try` are not failable (they don't `throw`), so you cannot mark them `try` in the first place.

The entire attempt to turn this situation into a try/catch is wrong-headed. What you want to do here is simply add a condition to *check* whether the desired element [exists](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500760-exists) and [is tappable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500561-ishittable), and proceed differently if it doesn't (i.e. don't attempt to tap it). That is what `if` is for.

(Of course one might argue that if the test is not intended to fail if it is impossible to `tap` this element, then the test *itself* is incorrectly constructed — you should just omit the `tap` line altogether.)