# AVAudioPlayerNode.play() causes crash after backgrounding and foregrounding the app

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, core-audio, watchos, avaudioplayernode

I'm working on a watchOS app which plays sound using an AVAudioPlayerNode. Whenever I put the app in the background, open it back again and try to play sound, the app crashes with the following message:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'player did not see an IO cycle.'

If I use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36454808/3151675) to catch NSExceptions in Swift, the following error appears:

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio error 0.)

Comment: I experienced a similar issue, but stopping the old/running instance before creating a new one, seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe `WKExtension.applicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`.

Whenever it gets posted:

- reinitialize the AVAudioEngine instance you're using (`audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()`)
- reattach all the nodes